# Memory usage goes up after adding UIImageView programmatically

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I wanted to write an action, which adds an image to the view when button is pressed

```
-(IBAction)AddButtonTouch:(id)sender {

UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20+[[self.SumTextField text]integerValue]*8, 220, 8, 40)] ;
NSString *imgFilepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pet" ofType:@"jpg"];
[imgView setImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imgFilepath]];

[self.view addSubview:imgView];
}
```

every time the Action is called usage of devices memory rises by 5MB. The solution is possibly very simple, but i need help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory rise is expected, because every time the button is tapped you are adding *yet another new image view*. They are just piling up on top of each other. And each one has an image and hence a large backing store.

To reduce memory usage:

- Don't add another image view if you don't have to.
- If you do have to, reduce the image size to its display size (easy to do in code) *before* handing it to the image view. Remember, an image held in memory requires more RAM *exponentially* as its size increases.

Comment: Thank you. The size of my image was not the same as the size of ImageView frame and that casused memmory usage to rise.

Comment: @user2638817 Glad you got it sorted. One image view with a large image is okay, but as soon as you have multiple image views with large images, memory piles up quickly (and your app will probably crash).

Answer (score 0):

Yes with the current code every time you tap the button you create a new UIImageView and you add it on top of the previous. If this is not intentional I would recommend you to store this in an iVar in order to reuse it / check if it's already present and modify the logic in the action method accordingly.